# CMake and vcpkg x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenGL32 when cross compiling

Tags: linux, cmake, mingw, cross-compiling, linker-errors

I'm making project which uses sfml, imgui-sfml and nlohmann json. For my dependences im using vcpkg. My host machine is Arch and I wanna cross build to Windows x64. Im getting strange linking error, am I missing something easy here? Here is my toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x64)

# which tools to use
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32)


# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

here is my custom triplet:

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)

set(VCPKG_CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MinGW)
set(VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/sokoban/toolchain-minwin.cmake)
```

my CMakeLists.txt(im not using anywhere raw opengl, only sfml)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0079 NEW)

project(sokoban VERSION 0.0.0
                DESCRIPTION "Sokoban"
                LANGUAGES CXX)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
endif()


#c++17 standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
add_compile_options(-std=c++17)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

add_subdirectory(src)

#commented or not same error
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

find_package(freetype CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(nlohmann_json CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system window graphics CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(ImGui-SFML CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(imgui CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(sokoban PRIVATE nlohmann_json nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
target_link_libraries(sokoban PRIVATE sfml-system sfml-network sfml-graphics sfml-window)
target_link_libraries(sokoban PRIVATE ImGui-SFML::ImGui-SFML)
target_link_libraries(sokoban PRIVATE imgui::imgui)
target_link_libraries(sokoban PRIVATE freetype)
```

and my error

```
[bor@b0x build]$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake  -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-custom -DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/sokoban/toolchain-minwin.cmake
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenGL: opengl32   
-- Found ZLIB: optimized;/home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/installed/x64-custom/lib/libzlib.a;debug;/home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/installed/x64-custom/debug/lib/libzlibd.a (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found BZip2: optimized;/home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/installed/x64-custom/lib/libbz2.a;debug;/home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/installed/x64-custom/debug/lib/libbz2d.a (found version "1.0.8") 
-- Looking for BZ2_bzCompressInit
-- Looking for BZ2_bzCompressInit - found
-- Found PNG: optimized;/home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/installed/x64-custom/debug/lib/libpng.a;debug;/home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/installed/x64-custom/debug/lib/libpng16d.a (found version "1.6.37") 
-- Found nlohmann_json: /home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/installed/x64-custom/share/nlohmann_json/nlohmann_jsonConfig.cmake (found version "3.9.1") 
-- Found Freetype: optimized;/home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/installed/x64-custom/lib/libfreetype.a;debug;/home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/installed/x64-custom/debug/lib/libfreetyped.a (found version "2.10.4") 
-- Found SFML 2.5.1 in /home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/vcpkg/installed/x64-custom/share/sfml
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/bor/Dokumenty/proj/sokoban/build
[bor@b0x build]$ make
Scanning dependencies of target sokoban
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/main.cpp.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/Game.cpp.obj
[ 30%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/states/PlayingState.cpp.obj
[ 40%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/states/MainMenuState.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/states/LevelEditorState.cpp.obj
[ 60%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/Level.cpp.obj
[ 70%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/LevelConfig.cpp.obj
[ 80%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/objects/Player.cpp.obj
[ 90%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/map/Map.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../sokoban.exe
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenGL32
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/build.make:255: sokoban.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:133: src/CMakeFiles/sokoban.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please, show (add to the question post) the code (`CMakeLists.txt`) which links with OpenGL.

Comment: @Tsyvarev added

Comment: I see `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)` call, but don't see a call to `target_link_libraries` which uses its result. Probably, the file `src/CMakeLists.txt` contains that call? In the current form, there is no `target_link_libraries` call which could emit `OpenGL32` library for the linker command line.

Comment: No, in src/CMakeLists.txt I have only my .cpp/.hpp files, I'm not linking opengl anywhere by myself, I think SFML does that? I added find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED) hoping that it can fix my problem but it doesn't. If remove find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED) error is still the same:(

Comment: Well, it is very possible that `OpenGL32` is emitted when link with SFML. Probably, they have problem in configuration logic, which should create `OpenGL32` CMake target but doesn't create it actually. BTW, in your code you use `sfml-network` target but don't request `network` component from `find_package(SFML)`.

Comment: Can I do anything to get this work? Any hotfix? I also noticed that opengl is used by imgui-sfml, so its maybe imgui-sfml problem?
`[bor@b0x build]$ ../../vcpkg/vcpkg remove opengl --recurse  --triplet x64-mingw-static --host-triplet=x64-linux
The following packages will be removed:
  * imgui-sfml:x64-mingw-static
    opengl:x64-mingw-static
Additional packages (*) need to be removed to complete this operation.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by symlinking libopengl32.a with libOpenGL32.a. Maybe its dirty but atleast it works. I don't know if that is typo in imgui/sfml packages or what.

```sh
ln -s /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libopengl32.a /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libOpenGL32.a
```